# Copying XML File to Write to New XML File in Java

Tags: java, xml, file-io, xml-parsing, bufferedreader

I was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to use one of the XML parsers in Java to read line-by-line, each of the rows in an XML document and basically reproduce the same document in another XML file? (In my case, take only the lines from Point X to Point Y in the document and copy them). I thought about using using the bufferedreader and bufferedwriter in a small trial run, but it did not quite output the file properly. Below is what I was doing in my trial run, but it is not what I want. So does anyone have any experience with this or have any thoughts or suggestions to offer? Thank you in advance.

**JAVA CODE**

```
public class IPDriver 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Documents and Settings/user/workspace/Intern Project/Proposals/Converted Proposals/Extracted Items/ProposalOne/word/document.xml"));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Documents and Settings/user/workspace/Intern Project/Proposals/Converted Proposals/Extracted Items/ProposalOne/word/tempdocument.xml"));

        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            writer.write(line);
        }

        // Close to unlock.
        reader.close();
        // Close to unlock and flush to disk.
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

**Working JAVA Code Thanks To Ted Hopp**

```
public class IPDriver 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/user/workspace/Intern Project/Proposals/Converted Proposals/Extracted Items/ProposalOne/word/document.xml"), "UTF-8"));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/user/workspace/Intern Project/Proposals/Converted Proposals/Extracted Items/ProposalOne/word/tempdocument.xml"), "UTF-8"));

            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                writer.write(line);
            }

            // Close to unlock.
            reader.close();
            // Close to unlock and flush to disk.
            writer.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why doesn't this work? Does It give an error or something?

Comment: What was wrong with the output? Im guessing you want to use an XML parser to get greater control/better output? I make this comment because your example code above doesnt use a parser at all.

Comment: Basically, before Ted's solution, I was getting like 1/20 of the original XML document before an error was reported in the new document referring to some style sheet error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your code didn't copy the file over properly, my guess is that you have a character encoding problem. Since the default encoding for XML is UTF-8 and the default encoding for FileReader is the default encoding for your platform, I suggest doing this instead:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream("...input file path..."),
        "UTF-8"
    )
);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream("...output file path..."),
        "UTF-8"
    )
);
```

XML parsers will give you elements (or element events), not lines. For instance, they cannot distinguish between variations in white space:

```
<tag attr1="val1" attr2="val2" />
```

versus:

```
<tag attr1="val1"
     attr2="val2"
     />
```

If your requirements include distinguishing those two cases, then an XML parser approach would not work.

Comment: @Ted Hopp, that worked! Thank you so much. However, for what I am trying to do. I am not sure exactly what to add to my code to scrap only the sections I want.

For example, I would like to be able to identify an instance of "val" stored in ur example above....scrape everything beneath that 'row' until another instance of 'val' is found. Is that possible?

Comment: It depends, I think, on how much control you have over the contents of the files, how complex the XML structure is, and what you are looking for. I'd tend to use the DOM parser, do a little surgery to eliminate what I didn't want, generate XML from the modified DOM, and live with the loss of formatting. However, if you have a simple enough document structure, you can perhaps implement your own rough parsing using regular expression searches. The trick is to think through all the things that might be in the document that would mess up your code, and then defend against them. Not an easy task.

Comment: If you need data from XML, you should use XML parser -- that's one basic rule with XML. The only case where you don't need to parse is if you are making blind copy.

Comment: @Ted Hopp, @StaxMan My experience (thus far) is working with the SAX parser to extract out the necessary attributes I am looking for in a given xml document. The reason I was hesitant to use a Parser in this case was because (adding on to what I said before) in addition to scraping between heading1 & heading2, i want to identify if an instance of "image" exists between the two headings. If it does, then I want to keep that section in a separate document and parse through just that document looking for the target attributes (most likely with SAX).

Comment: @Ted Hopp, @StaxMan However, I believe the parsers only read down, they cannot read back up. So if I were to identify an instance of image using the parser, I would not be able to scrape out the section above it. So I'm not really sure how to best go about this now. :/

Comment: @This 0ne - I think you'll find the DOM parser easier for this than SAX. (It's a memory hog, but it does have its uses.) You can search for tags in subtrees easily, snip out parts you don't want, and generate XML from what's left easily enough using a Transformer.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a copy, do not make the rookie mistake of using a Reader but copy using InputStream/OutputStream. And even with Readers, why would you read it line by line? Just read buffer-fulls of characters.

So why avoid Reader? Because it adds overhead of decoding bytes to characters (and requiring a Writer to encode from chars to bytes), which is of no value to you. And that can also introduce issues, if you make another common mistake of not specifying encoding to use for Reader or Writer -- that will then use whatever platform default encoding is, which may or may not be encoding that File you are reading is using.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily link a reader and writer with StAX. Using that API, you could also easily create a filter to extract just the portions of the document you want. Here are a couple of links which might help:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipstx2/
- http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbfl.html#bnbgh

Comment: I would work with StAX, but I just started familiarizing myself with SAX and have incorporated it into a phase of my project. How different would you say StAX is from SAX?

Comment: Using SAX is often like trying to climb up the tree, ass first. Or writing expressions in reverse polish notation. Or, in CS speak: it is event-loop (listener) based, so you end up writing handlers, keeping track of state, all the complexity. Stax is more straight-forward; you read things using cursor (XMLStreamReader) in the order they are in the XML document; and can then write them similarly.

Comment: @This Like he said, StAX is pull-cursor based as opposed to the push model of SAX. This makes it well suited to what I think you're trying to do. You will do the job with less code and code that is probably more intuitive to write and read. That said, you could of course do the job with SAX. You could take the opportunity to learn both for your intern project. It will be time well spent.